# declared parsequery as an array of object but its throwing exception Java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I used parsequery as an array of object i have to dynamically create the no of parsequery objects based on the str length so I did like below but when i run it, it shows Java.lang.NullPointer Exception

```
package com.ahapunch.parse;

import android.util.Log;

import com.ahapunch.Listdata;
import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Search {
public ArrayList<Listdata> sl1=new ArrayList<Listdata>();
private ParseQuery<ParseObject>[] query;

public void search(String searchString)
{
       ArrayList<String> sl=new ArrayList<String>();
             String[] str= searchString.split("\\s+");
             /*for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++)
             {
               sl.add(str[i]);
                 System.out.println("lolo" + sl.get(i));
             }*/
    for(int j=0;j<str.length;j++)
    {

        query[j]=ParseQuery.getQuery("Audio");
        query[j].whereContains("audio_name",str[j]);
    }

    List<ParseQuery<ParseObject>> queries = new ArrayList<ParseQuery<ParseObject>>();
    for(int j=0;j<str.length;j++)
    {
    queries.add(query[j]);
    }
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> mainQuery = ParseQuery.or(queries);

        Log.d("second", "second");
        mainQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> audioList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    if (audioList.size() > 0) {
                        System.out.println("size" + audioList.size());
                        for (int i = 0; i < audioList.size(); i++) {
                            ParseObject p = audioList.get(i);
                            String name = p.getString("audio_name");
                            Listdata l = new Listdata();
                            l.audio_name = p.getString("audio_name");
                            l.audio_category = p.getString("audio_category");
                            l.audio_movie = p.getString("audio_movie");
                            l.audio_actor = p.getString("audio_actor");
                            l.audio_clip = p.getParseFile("audio_clip");
                            l.audio_thumbnail = p.getParseFile("audio_thumbnail");
                            sl1.add(l);

                            System.out.println("normal search" + sl1.get(i).audio_name);
                            //System.out.println(audio_name.get(i)+" "+audio_category.get(i)+" "+audio_movie.get(i)+" "+audio_actor.get(i)+" "+audio_thumbnail.get(i) +" "+audio_clip.get(i));
                        }


                    } else {
                        System.out.println("no audio u searched for");
                    }

                } else {
                    Log.d("ohgaya", "ohgaya");

                }
            }
        });
    //}

}
```

}

I get an error as

```
      05-26 12:56:45.157  30931-30931/com.ahapunch E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ahapunch, PID: 30931
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ahapunch.parse.Search.search(Search.java:39)
        at com.ahapunch.SignUpActivity$1.onClick(SignUpActivity.java:62)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4456)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18465)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you haven't initialized the array `ParseQuery<ParseObject>[] query`.

Try adding this line: `query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>[str.length];` after you split the search string.